# Rewriting an odd function

Tags: reflection, f#

I have the following function, which feels a bit odd. There may be an idiom or pattern I'm replicating that's already built-in. The function should lazily return loaded assemblies and their references. Upon each invocation, it should return the full list of assemblies discovered thus far, along with newly "discovered" assemblies, until iteration stops. Is there a better way to write this?

```
let discoverAssemblies =
  let known = HashSet()
  let rec discover (assemblies:array<Assembly>) =
    seq {
      for asm in assemblies do
        if known.Add(asm) then
          yield asm
          let refs = 
            asm.GetReferencedAssemblies() 
            |> Array.map (fun asmName -> Assembly.Load(asmName))
          yield! discover refs
    }
  fun () ->
    seq {
      for asm in known do yield asm
      yield! AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |> discover
    }
```

By the way, I haven't tested it and there's a good chance it's buggy. Thus rely on the description more than the code.

#### EDIT

It seems `LazyList` or `Seq.cache` would be suitable, but `GetAssemblies()` is non-deterministic. However, it seems, once all referenced assemblies have been loaded, `GetAssemblies()` would return the same thing as a resursive traversal of `GetReferencedAssemblies()`. Can anyone confirm this? If that's the case, more straightforward solutions are possible.

Comment: `LazyList` or `Seq.cache` would help you to write this without storing the generated assemblies in a `HashSet` (you could recursively access the assemblies generated so far to test if you already generated that one). However, using `HashSet` is more efficient, so it seems like a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a function that would capture this pattern anywhere in the F# library. However, it definitely feels like something that might be useful. The reusable pattern is to use a specified "generating function" to generate all elements of some set from the set of a few initial elements (mathematicians would probably call it a *fixed point of a generating function*).

It may be worth capturing the pattern in a reusable function like this:

```
module Seq =
  /// Uses the specified generating function 'f' to generate items
  /// from each of the specified initial values. Then continues
  /// generating values repeatedly until all values are produced.
  let generateUnique f (initial:seq<'T>) =
    let known = HashSet()
    let rec loop initial = seq {
      for itm in initial do
        if known.Add(itm) then
          yield itm
          yield! loop (f itm) }
    loop initial
```

Then you could write your function for discovering assemblies using `Seq.generateUniqe` like this:

```
let discoverAssemblies() =
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() 
  |> Seq.generateUnique (fun asm ->
      asm.GetReferencedAssemblies()
      |> Seq.map Assembly.Load)
```

Comment: Thanks for articulating the pattern so well...and for the implementation.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks, although I didn't really answer your question. It feels like there may be something useful for implementing this somewhere in the F# library...

Comment: If you run across something, please update your answer. For now, this will allow me to simplify the code sufficiently.

Comment: floodfill would be an appropriate description for this algorithm.

Comment: @Tomas: Is it important to use `HashIdentity.Structural` here?

Comment: @Tomas: Unfortunately, this doesn't achieve the desired behavior. I posted an answer with my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

My function (and, in turn, Tomas' excellent implementation of it) doesn't have the desired behavior. If iteration stops prior to all referenced assemblies being yielded, it's possible that the remaining references will never be visited (because the referencing assembly is already "known").

I ended up with:

```
module Seq =
  let generateUnique f =
    let known = HashSet()
    fun initial ->
      let rec loop items = 
        seq {
          let cachedSeq = items |> Seq.filter known.Add |> Seq.cache
          if not (cachedSeq |> Seq.isEmpty) then
            yield! cachedSeq
            yield! loop (cachedSeq |> Seq.collect f)
        }
      loop initial

let discoverAssemblies =
  let discover = Seq.generateUnique (fun (asm:Assembly) -> asm.GetReferencedAssemblies() |> Seq.map Assembly.Load)
  fun () -> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |> discover
```